# kivymd invalid property name error when using root.manager.transition

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

When I run the code I get an invalid property name error for the 24th line ("root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'"),

```
MDScreen:
    name:"main"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 0.149,0.654,0.352,1
    Image:
        source: "main_photo_1.png"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .65}
        size_hint: .5,.5
    MDLabel:
        text: "'welcome"
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {"center_y": .34}
        halign: "center"
        color: rgba(34,34,34,255)
    Button:
        text: ""
        size_hint: .66, .065
        background_color: 0,0,0,0
        Image:
            source: "log in.png"
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.current = "login"
```

also, here is the python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.lang import Builder

Window.size = (310,580)
Builder.load_file("login.kv")


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('main.kv'))
        return screen_manager



MyApp().run()
```

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the properties/events of a widget in the `kv` must appear before its children. Try moving the `on_press` to before the `Image`:

```
Button:
    text: ""
    size_hint: .66, .065
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    on_press:
        root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        root.manager.current = "login"
    Image:
        source: "log in.png"
        center_x: self.parent.center_x
        center_y: self.parent.center_y
```